# MYSQL IF NOT LIKE A THEN LIKE B

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-like

i want to make a sql query l
but how do I perform an IF...THEN in an SQL SELECT statement like: "
select name from table1,table2 where if( name like a then name like a ) else name like b"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OR` operator, which connects two Boolean clauses:

```
WHERE name LIKE ...
   OR name LIKE ...
```

Note that `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`, so if you want to combine this with other restrictions, you'll need to use parentheses; for example:

```
WHERE ( name LIKE '%a%' OR name LIKE '%b%' )
  AND id < 1000
```

Comment: i can't use "or" because i can't chose both a and b just only a or b

Comment: I want to make an query can check completely null for example: select a where case when a like %b% then a like %b% else (if after search every row of table still return null) a like %c% (if have match in any row skip else statement) can u help me

Answer (score 1):

SQL isn't a programming language, it doesn't have if, then, else etc.  If the required condition can be expressed in set operations such as AND and OR you can do it.

Otherwise you need to write a Stored Procedure, Stored Function or Stored Routine.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html, which will allow you to write procedural code.  The set operations are usually much faster.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports `IF` statements and `CASE` statements.  Try something like this assuming a and b are columns in one of your tables and name is a column in your other table:

```
 select name 
    from table1,table2
    where name like 
       case 
          when name like a 
          then a
          else b
       end
```

And some sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6ce6/1

You may be wanting to use '%' with your LIKE query -- if so, CONCAT accordingly.  This same logic can be used with string values instead if needed.

Please post your table structure, sample data, and desired output so we can fully understand your question though and provide the best answer.

Comment: @KhoaTrumcuoi -- np, glad we could help!  BTW -- if any of the answers helped you, consider marking them accepted so future users of the site will know your issue has been resolved.  Best of luck!

Comment: sorr but i don't known understand ur mean how to  "marking them accepted" bescase i'm just a newbie ^^ sorr

Comment: @KhoaTrumcuoi: To the left of each answer, you should see the outline of a checkbox. If you click on it, the checkbox will become filled in, and it will mark that answer as the accepted answer. (See ["How does accepting an answer work?" on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/172535).)

Answer (score 0):

Ever tried mysql stored procedure http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx?

And you may want to check this out: [using "if" and "else" Stored Procedures MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326082/using-if-and-else-stored-procedures-mysql)

Hope this helps! :)