# SQL - Can I do something like if this isn't true do the other part

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Can I do a if on sql like if :P_Prestay is true do this aprt, else do this other. This is what i tried but has syntax error and i dont know how can I do it

```
AND R.RES_ESTRES = 'CM'
AND R.RES_SISCRE IN ('MPH','HPH')
**((AND BOOKINGENGINECODE = :P_BOOKINGENGINECODE
AND :P_PRESTAY like 'true')
(AND TRUNC(R.RES_FECINI) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)+2
and :P_POSTSTAY like 'true'
AND TRUNC(R.RES_FECFIN) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)-1))**
```

sry for my english.

Comment: Please add your complete query, input and expected output

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  Are the variables prefaced by colon some sort of positional parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `AND` outside the brackets:

```
AND R.RES_ESTRES = 'CM'
AND R.RES_SISCRE IN ('MPH','HPH')
AND (  (
           :P_PRESTAY = 'true'
       AND BOOKINGENGINECODE = :P_BOOKINGENGINECODE
       )
    OR (
           ( :P_PRESTAY <> 'true' OR :P_PRESTAY IS NULL ) -- This will only be true if
                                                          -- the previous condition is not
                                                          -- true.
       AND :P_POSTSTAY  = 'true'
       AND R.RES_FECINI >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 2
       AND R.RES_FECINI <  TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + 3
       AND R.RES_FECFIN >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - 1
       AND R.RES_FECFIN <  TRUNC( SYSDATE )
       )
    )
```

Also, if you use `TRUNC( datevalue )` then Oracle cannot use an index on the column and would need a function-based index so it is often more efficient to specify the range of date values and not compare truncated dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create PL block or procedure parameters. Check Parameter values using if condition.
Check following links:

https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS386
 or
[using "if" and "else" Stored Procedures MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326082/using-if-and-else-stored-procedures-mysql)

Comment: The question is tagged `SQL` not `PL/SQL` and this is a link-only answer. If you feel that the links answer the question then quote the relevant parts and explain how to apply it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case-statement in your condition

```
with tab1 as (select 1 "ID", 1 "TAKECOL", 10 "C1", 20 "C2" from dual
union all select 2 "ID", 1 "TAKECOL", 10 "C1", 20 "C2" from dual
union all select 3 "ID", 2 "TAKECOL", 20 "C1", 10 "C2" from dual
union all select 4 "ID", 2 "TAKECOL", 20 "C1", 20 "C2" from dual)
select * 
from tab1
where case takecol 
        when 1 then c1 
        else c2 
      end = 10;
```

This returns ID 1,2 and 3 but not 4

For the definition of case see [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm)